# X2Go Error: X server does not support XInput 2

Tags: remote-access, glx, openfoam, x2go

I am using the remote desktop software X2Go to use an Ubuntu 20.04 linux workstation from remote. I am tunneling from an Ubuntu 20.04 laptop. Initially, everything seems to work fine. When I start paraFoam, i get the following error message:

`qt.qpa.xcb: X server does not support XInput 2`

`Aborted (core dumped)`

Any ideas what could cause this problem?
I am using the mate-desktop-environment, had the exact same problem with xfce.

There is a thread relating to this in the X2Go mail archive, leading to a solution for Ubuntu 14. Has anyone tried this and can give detailed instructions?

Thread:
https://www.mail-archive.com/x2go-user@lists.x2go.org/msg04042.html

Workaround: https://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php/wiki:development:glx-xlib-workaround

Comment: Did you find an answer?